# Convergence of double series with simple powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following three series:
$$
s_1=\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \frac{ij}{(i+j)^{a/2+1}}\,,
\quad\quad
s_2=\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \frac{ij}{(i+j)^{a/2}}\,,
\quad\quad
s_3=\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \frac{i^2j^2}{(i+j)^{a/2+2}}\,,
$$
where $a$ is a positive integer. I wonder for which values of $a$, the three series $s_1$, $s_2$ and $s_3$ are divergent. In particular I am looking for a generic method to understand the divergence/convergence of these kind of multiple series, such as $\sum_{i,j,k=1}^\infty\frac{ij+jk+ik}{(i+j+k)^{a/2+1}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the series into question have the form
$$
S_{\alpha,\beta}=\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty\frac{(ij)^\alpha}{(i+j)^\beta}.
$$
Since the summand is symmetric in $i$ and $j$, it suffices to examine the convergence of
$$
S'_{a,b}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^j\frac{(ij)^\alpha}{(i+j)^\beta}.
$$
Letting $x_j:=\sum_{i=1}^j\frac{(ij)^\alpha}{(i+j)^\beta}$,
one has
$$
x_j\leqslant \frac{j^\alpha}{j^\beta}\sum_{i=1}^ji^\alpha\leqslant j^{2\alpha+1-\beta}.
$$

and $$x_j\geqslant\sum_{i=1}^j\mathbf{1}_{j/2\leqslant i\leqslant j}\frac{(ij)^\alpha}{(i+j)^\beta}\geqslant cj^{2\alpha+1-\beta}, $$
where $c$ is independent of $j$. Therefore, $S_{\alpha,\beta}$ converges if and only if $\beta-2\alpha>2$.

Comment: Basically the method is to understand the behaviour of $x_j$ for large $j$. Another more general method is provided by the comments of Robert Z. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

My comments are a complement to Giraudo's answer.

Considering the last series, we have that
$$\sum_{i,j,k=1}^\infty\frac{ij+jk+ik}{(i+j+k)^{a/2+1}}
=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{a/2+1}}\sum_{i,j,k\geq 1,i+j+k=n}(ij+jk+ik)=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{3\binom{n+1}{4}}{n^{a/2+1}}.$$
(see [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%28sum%28i*j%2Bj*%28n-i-j%29%2B%28n-i-j%29*i%20%2Cj%3D1%20to%20n-1-i%29%2Ci%3D1%20to%20n-2%29) for the last step, in general $\sum_{i,j,k\geq 1,i+j+k=n}(ij+jk+ik)^\alpha\sim c\cdot n^{2(\alpha+1)}$).
Since
$$\frac{3\binom{n+1}{4}}{n^{a/2+1}}\sim \frac{n^4/8}{n^{a/2+1}}=
\frac{1/8}{n^{a/2-3}},$$
it follows that the series is convergent if and only if
$a/2-3>1$, that is for $a>8$.

Moreover, notice that when $a$ is an even integer then the sum can be written as a linear combination of zeta values:
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{i,j,k=1}^\infty\frac{ij+jk+ik}{(i+j+k)^{a/2+1}}&=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{2n-n^2-2n^3+n^4}{n^{a/2+1}}\\
&=\frac{\zeta(a/2)}{4}-\frac{\zeta(a/2-1)}{8}-\frac{\zeta(a/2-2)}{4}+\frac{\zeta(a/2-3)}{8}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! Do you have any suggestions for the general case $\sum_{i,j,k\geq 1,i+j+k=n}(ij+jk+ik)^\alpha$ ? WA doesn’t give any result in this case

Comment: $\sum_{i,j,k\geq 1,i+j+k=n}(ij+jk+ik)^\alpha\sim n^{2(\alpha+1)}$. Use WA after setting $\alpha$ with a specific value.

Comment: I'm really grateful!